# How to retrieve data from MySQL DB to GridView in ASP

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using `MySQL` as DB and I want to retrieve table data to `GridView` in my browser. Below is the code I am using, there are no errors but if I run the page, it shows blank

```
MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=;password=;database=workers;");
string strSQL = "select * from details";
MySqlDataAdapter mydata = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myconn);
MySqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mydata);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
mydata.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
myconn.Close();
```

I have tried with `Microsoft SQL Server` DB by adding DB file and same content in DB, then it worked.

Comment: What do you mean adding content in DB? Are you saying there isn't already content/data (in which case the result is entirely expected)?

Comment: your first comment was what is value of myconn

Comment: @SkonJeet asked question "what is value of myconn" in comment, edited comment and now pretending that you cant understand what I was talking about that's funny... Ok forget it.

Comment: I didn't. And even if I did - "open your eyes" - there's no need to be rude like that.

Comment: by writing "open your eyes" I wanted to say look at the question again , sorry if that looked rude for you (English isn't my native language)

Comment: @Reniuz - apology accepted. You're obviously competent enough in English to write "look at the question again" so I don't really know how that mistake was made in the first place but you've said sorry so that's fine.

Comment: @Skonjeet  What I mean by this line is " have tried with Microsoft SQL Server DB by adding DB file and same content in DB" ...                                I have started with a new website and added database to that project and now I have dragged gridview on new form and simply linked to microsoft database after then I created some tables in Database. In this way browser shows me gridview with some table contents when I run the website..

Comment: @SkonJeet kindly tell me if there is any wrong with my code

Comment: Not that I can see, but it'd be beneficial for you to use breakpoints and check the values of myData and the ds (after filling it).

Comment: @SkonJeet I tried using breakpoints, the same thing happens it reads each and every line of code but with no errors

Comment: The same thing *will* happen obviously, breakpoints won't change the way this sort of code is executed. The purpose of them in this context is to find out were the problem is more specifically. You need to find out what one of those variables is not holding the value that you would expect.

Comment: @skonjeet I have found the problem.. I have tried with magnifier when we insert break points, at this point GridView1.DataSource = ds; Here it show me table content and next step it is not binding data to gridview.. this is the problem. Please help me if you have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not open your connections. try it by adding this

```
myconn.open();
```

before this line

```
MySqlDataAdapter mydata = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myconn);
```

Comment: Sir, I am using a DataAdapter which we dont need to write code to open and close for database. Also I have tried with magnifier when we insert break points, at this point GridView1.DataSource = ds;             Here it show me table content and next step it is not binding data to gridview.. this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

open your database connections